# Create Modern Sites in SharePoint Online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, communication-site, modern-team-site

Can we create **Modern Team site** and **Communication sites** using CSOM  in SharePoint Online ?

I tried to create the modern site for **GROUP#0** and  **SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0** with the below code sample and getting the error
  `The web template SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0 is not available for sites on this tenant.`

```
string tenantadminurl = tenantAdminUrl.Replace("-admin", "").Trim() + "/sites/";
                // TemplateName = "Modern Team Site", TemplateID = "GROUP#0" 
                // TemplateName = "Modern Communication", TemplateID = "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0" 
                //string siteurl = tenantadminurl + objSiteCollectionDetails.SiteTitle;
                // string tenanturl = tenantAdminUrl.Replace("-admin", "").Trim();
                string siteurl = "https://tarundev-admin.sharepoint.com" + "/sites/"+"SampleMDsite";
                // string siteurl = "https://tarundev.sharepoint.com" + "/sites/"+"SampleMDsite";
                objSiteProperties.SiteUrl = siteurl;
                var tenant = new Tenant(context);
                var properties = new SiteCreationProperties()
                {
                    CompatibilityLevel = 15,
                    Title = objSiteCollectionDetails.SiteTitle,
                    Url = siteurl,
                    Owner = owner,
                    Template = objSiteCollectionDetails.SiteTemplate,
                    StorageMaximumLevel = 1,
                    UserCodeMaximumLevel = 300
                };
                tenant.CreateSite(properties);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Can anyone guide me in the right way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not possible currently using OOTB SPO CSOM.

However, using the latest PnP Core and PnP PowerShell components, you will be able to create them programmatically.

**Using CSOM C#**

You can use the below code to create Communication site:

```
CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation communicationSiteInfo = new CommunicationSiteCollectionCreationInformation
{
    Title = "Test Communication Site",
    Url = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/TestCommunicationSite",
    //possible SiteDesign values can be
    //SiteDesign = CommunicationSiteDesign.Showcase,
    //SiteDesign = CommunicationSiteDesign.Blank,
    SiteDesign = CommunicationSiteDesign.Topic,
    Description = "Test modern communication site description",
    Owner = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
    AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers = true,
    //Classification = "HR",
    //Lcid = 1033
};

var createCommSite = await context.CreateSiteAsync(communicationSiteInfo);
```

To create a Modern team site, you can use the below code:

```
TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation modernteamSiteInfo = new TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation
{
    Description = "Test modern teamsite description",
    DisplayName = "Test Modern Team Site",
    Alias = "TestModernTeamSite",
    IsPublic = true,
    //Classification="IT"                       
};

var createModernSite = await context.CreateSiteAsync(modernteamSiteInfo);
```

These are currently in beta and may not always work as expected.

To install the latest PnP core, go to your `Project References > Manage nuget packages`.

Download the `SharePointPnPCoreOnline` component. Its version should be `2.20.1711` or higher (i.e Nov 2017 or higher).

[image]

You also need to add the statement `using OfficeDevPnP.Core.Sites;` in your class.

To create "Modern" unified team site(with associated Azure AD group) , you can also follow the approach that I have mentioned [here](https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/10/16/create-o365-groups-with-csom-c/) which requires access to Azure portal.

**Using PnP PowerShell**

To provision these site programmatically using PowerShell, you can use the `PnP PowerShell` commandlets mentioned below. Download the latest `PnP PowerShell (November 2017) or higher)` so that these commands are available.

For Communication site -

```
New-PnPSite -Type CommunicationSite -Title "Test Communication Site"
-Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testCommunicationSite" 
-SiteDesign Showcase -AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers
```

For Modern team site -

```
New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title "Test ModernTeam Site" -Alias "TestModernTeamSite" -IsPublic
```

Reference - [New-PnPSite](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/New-PnPSite.md)

Download link - [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Comment: Your solutions worked for one day after that site is not creating. No exception and no output. What may be the reason. Because of Beta Version

Comment: yes beta version. I would suggest that you wait for couple of days for this to be stable.

Comment: What is the  context required to create the modern site either 
 tenant( https://tenant.sharepoint.com/ )  or  tenantadmin (https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/ )

Comment: The context required is `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite`. I used a global admin account, but sometime back tested with a normal account and was able to create site collection. Like I said,this is beta, so I guess they are allowing "everyone" to create site collection :(

Comment: "App-Only is currently not supported." This error i am getting while creating the  Modern Team Site..

Comment: hey, App-only provisioning is not supported yet. So, you need to use username and password for this :(