# Modern team site error

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

when I create team site using the code from the following URL:
 [Create Modern Sites in SharePoint Online using CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/create-modern-sites-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom)

it show the error in the given image.

[image]

Comment: can you paste the code ? Looks like its a bit different from what is there in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using this code in a console application.

It looks like your code is executing before the team site is created which causes the 404 error.

You need to wait for the site to be created using the `Wait` or `GetAwaiter` method as below in a console application:

```
TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation modernteamSiteInfo = new TeamSiteCollectionCreationInformation
{
    Description = "Test modern teamsite description",
    DisplayName = "Test Modern Team Site",
    Alias = "TestModernTeamSite",
    IsPublic = true,
    //Classification="IT"                       
};

var createModernSite = context.CreateSiteAsync(modernteamSiteInfo).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
// further code once the site is created
```

or

```
context.CreateSiteAsync(modernteamSiteInfo).Wait();
```

Use this in the console and write your code after the `Wait`.

Comment: thanks alot 
var createModernSite = context.CreateSiteAsync(modernteamSiteInfo).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
// this is working fine 
again thanks Sir :)

Comment: Can we set the owner of team site ?

Comment: Yes, we can. Can you ask it as another question? I will attempt to answer there. I can't answer it in the comments as its a bit long and also out of scope for the current question :)